# Approximate the expectation value of maximum of correlated random variables

Tags: probability, poisson-process

I am trying to find the expectation value of the maximal of some correlated random variables generated by Poisson point process (PPP).

Assume homogeneous PPP are on the 2-D plane with density $\lambda$. There are three overlapping hexagons demonstrated in the figure.

[image: three overlapping hexagons]

What is the expectation value of maximal number of points in one of the three hexagons?

Mathematically, the problem is described as follows:

Denote $X_i$ as the number of the points in the area $A_i$. Then, $Y_1=X_1+X_4+X_5+X_7$, $Y_2=X_2+X_4+X_6+X_7$ and $Y_3=X_3+X_5+X_6+X_7$ are the number of the points in the three hexagons, respectively. Calculate or approximate $E[\max(Y_1,Y_2,Y_3)]$.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but here is a python script to help estimate it:

I got approx. $6\frac{2}{3}\lambda A_7$ (assuming all the small triangles have the same area, and the larger ones are just three times the area.

```
from typing import List
from scipy.stats import poisson

# ppp definition
_lambda = 7
AREAS = [3, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1]
ppp = [poisson(a*_lambda) for a in AREAS]

# map partition
HEXAGONS = {1: [0, 3, 4, 6], 2: [1, 3, 5, 6], 3: [2, 4, 5, 6]}

def ppp_realization() -> List[int]:
    """
    Return a realization of the poisson point process for each partition.
    """
    return [i.rvs(1)[0] for i in ppp]

def hex_count(hex_id: int, partition_vars:List[int]) -> int:
    """
    Calculate the counts inside the hexagon with hex_id given a realization of the 
    random variables associated with the partitioned area.
    """
    return sum(partition_vars[i] for i in HEXAGONS[hex_id])

def run_exp(n_runs:int = 1000) -> float:
    maxima_sum = 0
    for r in range(n_runs):
        area_counts = ppp_realization()
        hex_counts = [hex_count(i,area_counts) for i in HEXAGONS]
        maxima_sum += max(hex_counts)
    return maxima_sum/n_runs
```